# Google app Engine integration with IOS

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, ios7, xcode5

I am developing an app in ios 7 using Google app engine as backend.I followed this link https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios
Our google console project is configured for IOS.
But the problem is when i am try to access any API I get this message:

Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=404 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Not Found)" UserInfo=0x17d3dd20 {error=Not Found, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x17e54e40: {message:"Not Found" code:404 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Not Found)}

The client side code:

```
static GTLServicePersonendpoint *service = nil;
if (!service) {
    service = [[GTLServicePersonendpoint alloc] init];
    service.retryEnabled = YES;
    [GTMHTTPFetcher setLoggingEnabled:YES];
}



[service executeQuery:querry completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLPersonendpointPersonInfoWrapper* object,NSError *error){




    NSLog(@"Signpu error: %@",[error description]);
    NSLog(@"Signup object %@",[object description]);


}];
```

Can any one suggest me any solution and the reason behind this problem?

Comment: Your account is not properly setup in google+

Comment: Can you post relevant portions of your server and client code?  You'll want to check that the client is using the correct names when calling the server.  You may also want to test the server with a simpler client.

Comment: @Ganesh ,I can use google plus signup using the same project.So I think the project setup is correct.

Comment: @DanSanderson When I'm running any query using gtlservice's extended class I got the error.

Comment: The problem is solved, the problem was with the wrong url.

Comment: @RabbyAlam I am having a similar issue. Could you tell me a bit more about what fixed the issue for you?